# Can the cardinality of the set of all intervening cardinals between sets and their power sets be always singular?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, large-cardinals

Is the following known to be consistent relative to some large cardinal assumption?

$\forall \kappa [\kappa >2 \to \kappa < \kappa^* < 2^\kappa \wedge singular(\kappa^*)]$

where $\kappa$ is a cardinal and $``<"$ is strict cardinal smaller than, and $\kappa^* = |\{\lambda|\kappa < \lambda < 2^\kappa\}|$

Comment: Wouldn't it be wise and prudent to first receive an answer to your previous question before asking follow ups?

Comment: @AsafKaragila,...hmmm..., well, not always!